# possible loss of precision required int found double array

Tags: java, arrays, int, double

I have read a file and require the variables to be doubles as they are decimals.  So have done this:

```
String[] data = list.split("\\t");

        homes = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
        rate = Double.parseDouble(data[1]);
```

I am now trying to put the data in an array but am getting the following error:

> possible loss of precision
>   required: int
>   found: double array

I need the variables homes and rate to be in an array in order to do a calculation and need them to be doubles as rate is a percentage in decimal:

```
private boolean [][] place = new boolean [homes][rate];
```

How can I stop this error?

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you need to initialize your array using **Integer** sizes, not `double`s. So you need to convert the doubles to integers.

Change

```
private boolean [][] place = new boolean [homes][rate];
```

to

```
private boolean [][] place = new boolean [(int)homes][(int)rate];
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Will that stop the values from being decimals though?

Comment: Yes, that will cause a loss of precision. But you don't need that extra precision if you're using the variables to initialize the array only. Or maybe, you could try `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Double.parseDouble()` from the first place.

Comment: I see, I would need it to be precise as its for my assignment. Is there a way I could read the data from the file and put them into arrays and then into the 'place' array?

Comment: You need integers to initialize your array. Try storing the file data in other variables.

Answer (score 0):

**arrays** by definition are indexed using integer *positions*. There is no slot number 9 3/4; that only exists in Harry Potter. You literally have to think of an array to look like this: `{true, false, true}` - what is the value at "1.75"?!?

If you want to "index" using arbitrary values, you may be looking for a *dictionary*, aka a `java.collections.Map` which maps keys (like 9.75) to values; or use a translation table from keys to indexes.